# Choose multiple images and upload with preview

Tags: javascript, image

I need to add multiple images for upload. Below is my form. In the form, if you kindly check **run code snippet`**, when I upload image one by one, images with preview shown but **no of images are not increased** (here shows 2 files though total 4 images are present). but when I select multiple images at a time, then no of selected images shows.

In the attached image, it shows 4 images but no of count shows only 2 files. This is the problem.

I want to know, is it possible to increase no of files, when I choose images one by one i.e. with single click and select one image?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {display: block;}
.imageThumb {max-height: 75px; border: 2px solid; padding: 1px; cursor: pointer;}
.pip {display: inline-block; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;}
.remove { display: block;background: #444;border: 1px solid black;color: white;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;}
.remove:hover {background: white;color: black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Upload your images</h3>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /></br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are relying on the browser's default `<input>`'s UI, which will only show its current content.

So if you want to upload all the Files that got selected, create an Array where you'll store all your Files, at every change.

Then to send it to your server, you will block the default behavior of your `<form>` by blocking its `submit` event, and sending a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) filled with your files through [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // First define the Array where we will store all our files
  var myFiles = [];
  // now, every time the user selects new Files,
  $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files, file;
    // iterate through all the given files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      file = files[i];
      myFiles.push(file); // store it in our array
      $('<span class="pip">' +
        '<img class="imageThumb" ' +
        // no need for a FileReader here,
        //  a blobURI is better (sync & uses less memory)
        'src="' + URL.createObjectURL(file) + '" ' +
        'title="' + file.name + '"/>' +
        '<br/>' +
        '<span class="remove">Remove image</span>' +
        '</span>')
      .insertAfter("#files")
      // add the event listener only on the new .remove
      .find(".remove").click(removeFile.bind(null, file));
    }
    updateCounters();
  });

  // now override the default form submission
  $('form').on('submit', upload);

  // removes both the preview elements from doc and the file from our array
  function removeFile(file, evt) {
    $(evt.target).parent(".pip").remove();
    myFiles.splice(myFiles.indexOf(file), 1);
    updateCounters();
  }
  // ...
  function updateCounters() {
    $('#counter').text(myFiles.length + ' files selected');
  }
  // from submission overriding function
  function upload(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // first block the default event
    var fd = new FormData(); // create a new FormData
    for (var i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
      fd.append('files[]', myFiles[i]); // append all our files to it
    }
    // Post the formdata through XHR
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'YOUR_FORM_ACTION_URL');
    // if you wanted to do something after the files are submitted
    // xhr.onload = callback;
    xhr.send(fd);
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
}

.imageThumb {
  max-height: 75px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Upload your images</h3>
  <span id="counter">0 files selected</span>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. When I am using script, after choosing files, submit button is not working. Plz help.

Comment: @dipakdutta You need to override the default behavior of your form to be able to send all these files. I already included a script to do so. You need to replace `yourURL` by your own URL you want to post to.

Comment: plz help me  how will I replace url and change default behavior of my form to be able to send all these files.

Comment: @dipakdutta I added comments in the answer, sorry I ran out of time just after I started writing this answer. So, you didn't included your form in your question, but basically, you just need to replace the `'yourURL'` *(or now `'YOUR_FORM_ACTION_URL'`)* string with the url you are posting to, i.e, your `<form>`'s `action` attribute.

Comment: Please Sir don't say `sorry` please. You are helping me.You are guiding ma. Now Submit button is working fine. But There is the same problem before..when selecting images one by one beside `choose files` button , single image name shows. and when selecting more than one images together , no of files shows beside `choose files` button. and  finally **no of files shows beside `choose files` button** inserts into database. not all selected files. as in the example 6 files selected but 3 files insert into database. check the link please  https://ibb.co/jZ7knw