# Not removing value from multifile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the following to upload and remove any file if clicked:

```
$(document).on('click','.close',function(){
  $(this).parents('span').remove();
})

document.getElementById("usp-files").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};

document.getElementById('usp-files').onchange = uploadOnChange;

function uploadOnChange() {
  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
      filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
  var files = $('#usp-files')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   $("#upload_prev").append('<span>'+files[i].name+'<p class="close">X</p></span>');
  }
  document.getElementById('filename').value = filename;
}
```

HTML

```
  <input type="hidden" id="uploadFile" placeholder="Add files from My Computer" class="steptextboxq3"/>
  <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Browse</span>
    <input name="usp-files[]" id="usp-files" type="file" maxlength="999999" data-required="false" placeholder="Upload your images here" class="upload sp-input usp-input-files my_images select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" name="browsefile">
  </div>
  <input id="filename" type="hidden" />
  <div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

Visually, we can see that it is removing it, but when I then send it to the server, it is saving all the files I have uploaded even tho I have removed them in front end.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tohgL1rb/6/)

Comment: Since only really modern browsers (Currently only Chrome and upcoming FF) allow us to edit a FileList, your only (viable) option is to store your Files in a conventional Array, and when requested to upload, append all the Array's items in a FormData that you would send through AJAX.

Comment: Highly related, and if you agree with it, I'd be fine to close it as dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735802/choose-multiple-images-and-upload-with-preview/47736121#47736121

Comment: @Kaiido ok just to make it sure, since my action is within the same page, you mention `xhr.open('POST', 'YOUR_FORM_ACTION_URL');` i guess i can just leave it blank instead of  `YOUR_FORM_ACTION_URL');` right?

Comment: Wait what? What do you mean by *my action is within the same page*? If you're not uploading these files to a server, you actually don't need FormData nor xhr, but what are you doing with it?

Comment: @Kaiido yes I am uploading them to the server, what I am saying is that the POST on my form has `action` not `action="www.link.com"` anyway I tried `xhr.open('POST', ''");` and `xhr.open('POST', ''www.myurl.com");` and when I hit the submit button just doesn't go anywhere

Comment: @Kaiido I tried     `$(".usp-submit").on("click", function(){
      upload();
    });` and then at the bottom of that `function upload()` I put `$("form").submit();`, then form now sends but it sends all the files selected ignoring the fact I have removed some

Comment: @Kaiido basically this `$("form").on('submit', upload);` won't let the form submit, and if I use the on click as per previous comment, it will send all the files ignoring what I have removed and send it anyway

Comment: yes that's the idea of the linled answer: block the default behavior (that is send all the files currently set in the form) and replicate it thrpugh AJAX. But your setup seems quite unusual, if I got it correctly you are providing your html from the same script that handles the upload, and you let the form redirect to the same page... Can't tell why, but I've got a bad feeling with this idea. And anyway I don't think you can replicate it with AJAX. So two options: change your setup to a more conventional one, or allow a single file per input and append/remove at each new/removed file

Comment: actually the page redirects to another page but the redirect is handled via php

Comment: @Kaiido yeah I give up, I will go with a add more.. and remove the input